# MW3: Care Package Specialities

Tags: nintendo-wii, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

In Black Ops, care packages sometimes contained bonuses like the grim reaper or the death machine.  Does Modern Warfare 3 have any special features with their care packages, or are they all available pointstreak items?

I should note I'm playing the wii version, which doesn't have all the PS3/XBOX features.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any care package drops which aren't also point streak rewards themselves.  In fact, care package drops from the Assault strike package will contain only Assault point streak rewards.

(I think the exception is Counter UAV - I feel like you might be able to get this from an Assault care package although it's a Support pointstreak)

The same applies for the Support pointstreak "Escort Airdrop" in the Support strike package; it will only drop Support pointstreak reward crates.

There are no "care package only" rewards similar to the way the Death Machine was in Black Ops.

Comment: Thanks, though I would beg to differ; I got the "Death Machine" from a care package in black ops (wii version); it's a gatling gun with 500 rounds of ammo... it's actually pretty cool...  I also got valkrie rockets and I don't recall seeing those as a regular weapon... at least in the wii version.

Comment: @Brian, uh, you asked about MW3, so I answered about MW3.  Yes, there are care package drops in *Black Ops* that you can't get otherwise.  It is not the same in MW3.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread your statement; I thought you were saying there were no special care package items in black ops.  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, I edited it to make it a bit clearer to help with your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

In black ops 
the care packages always give something low
In mw3 nd mw3 they give something high like a 9kill streak
I usually get a 9kill streak reward in them